# Accessing template constructor and function, both static and non-static

Tags: c++, templates, static

I'm new to template and find this thing rather confusing. I have a template class that serves as a table for mapping a entity to a string, my code for the class is like this

```
template<class GENERIC_ENTITY> class EntityTable
{
private:

    map<wstring, GENERIC_ENTITY*> entityTable;

    // I want to put init in the default constructor so it gets initialized, but this doesn't compile 
    EntityTable<GENERIC_ENTITY>::EntityTable () {
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
            entityTable[L"Entity1"] = new Entity1();
            entityTable[L"Entity2"] = new Entity2();
            entityTable[L"Entity3"] = new Entity3();
    }

public:

    // This function doesn't compile unless I remove the keyword static
    static template <class GENERIC_ENTITY> GENERIC_ENTITY retriveEntity(wstring identifier)
    {
        return entityTable[identifier];
    }
};
```

I then want to call this template function in another class and retrive corresponding entity using the `wstring` identifier. But unfortunately I can't either construct the class nor callig this function, no matter if the function is static. It doesn't even compile.

If the function is static I wanted to do something like `EntityTable<T>::retriveEntity(wstring)`, if not static I want to instantiate it first but I have no idea how to do it with template since I hear that template is not a class. I declared it as actual data on stack so I don't have to call new on the constructor which I have no idea what it is like, but I still cannot access that function.

I'm just utterly confused, can someone help me wrap my head around?

**Edit:**

BTW the way I declare this template in another class is as `template<class GENERIC_BOT> EntityTable entityTable;`. Not sure if this is correct

All Entity class are inherited from TWO common class (corrected the mistake of one) but those class is abstract, so I cannot instantiate it by just doing something like `Entity retrieveEntity(wstring info)`

I want this class to be a singleton of kind, construct it once where it gets initialized and call the static function eveywhere. The map is immutable after construction. `wstring` is passed to the template and template will return corresponding class associated with that `wstring` tag. I just need a fast way for retrival, giving the situation that the table is huge, I only showed two items for convenience.

P.S.
I know I could also return corresponding type using a if or switch statement, but that's long and cumbersome and defeats the purpose of using a map

Comment: Do `Entity1`, `Entity2` and `Entity3` all derive from some common parent class? I have a feeling they don't and you're trying to use templates to put objects of different types into a `std::map`.

Comment: It can't be `static` because it's accessing a member variable. And if you construct an instance of `EntityTable` on the fly in order to call `retrieveEntity()`, then its `entityTable` will be empty already. What exactly are you trying to do here? If it helps, get rid of the `template` and just define this class with a known value type, and then see if what you're doing makes sense.

Comment: entityTable isn't a static member of EntityTable, so you can't use it in static methods.

Comment: @sftrabbit They are all inherited from a common class but that class is abstract, so I cannot instantiate it by just doing something like `Entity retrieveEntity(wstring info)`

Comment: So what are you expecting people to pass as the `GENERIC_ENTITY` template argument? It'll only work if they do `EntityTable<EntityParent>`. What's the point of having a template if it only works with one template argument?

Comment: @Kevin Ballard I want this class to be a singleton of kind, construct it once where it gets initialized and call the static function eveywhere. Also those class are derived from an abstract class so I cannot use that class declaration for return type. I know I could also return corresponding type using a `if` or `switch` statement, but that's long and cumbersome and defeats the purpose of using a map

Comment: @sftrabbit I expect people to pass `wstring` to the template and template will return corresponding `class` associated with that `wstring` tag, the `class` is constructed and added in `init()` which is called inside the constructor so pretty much this map is immutable, I just need a fast way of retrival, giving the situation the table is huge, I only showed two items for convenience.

Comment: I'm still not sure why it's even a template. Why is it not just a `std::map<std::wstring, EntityParent*>`. What's the point of `GENERIC_ENTITY`?

Comment: @sftrabbit because those classes for derived from TWO abstract class (not from one as mistakenly stated before), sorry for the confusion :/ Let's say I want to try it that way to see if that's even techinically possible

Comment: The signature of `retriveEntity` is wrong. It must return `GENERIC_TEMPLATE*` and not `GENERIC_TEMPLATE`. Besides that the template is wrong, as you declare the function inside the class body. And not sure about this: The static modifier must occure after the template (typically youll format your code in a way, that the template is one line above the actually function signature). That you cant access a non static member inside a static method was already mentioned I think.

Comment: @ryf9059 If its part of your contract that the classes MUST derive from two concrete abstract classes at the same time then declare a intermediate class deriving from those two. All other classes then have to derive from this one. If the class CAN either derive from one or the other then go with two maps and two accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should compile fine:

```
template<class GENERIC_ENTITY> class EntityTable
{
private:

    map<wstring, GENERIC_ENTITY*> entityTable;

    EntityTable::EntityTable () {
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
            entityTable[L"Entity1"] = new Entity1();
            entityTable[L"Entity2"] = new Entity2();
            entityTable[L"Entity3"] = new Entity3();
    }

public:

    GENERIC_ENTITY* retriveEntity(wstring identifier)
    {
        return entityTable[identifier];
    }
};
```

If you want it to be static, simply apply the singleton pattern or declare entityTable static. In that case though, no constructor should be available and init() has to be static too and called at some point in your code. A singleton would guarantee that init() is just called once.